# Persistent cache during deployment with sphinx-autoapi?

Tags: python, gitlab, python-sphinx, docstring

I have been stuck with a problem for several days without solutions. I am trying to deploy local docs generated with Sphinx to Gitlab pages.

Below is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` on the root directory of the repos, and I am using the latest Ubuntu image:

```
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - apt update
  - apt install -y python3-pip
  - rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
  - pip install -U sphinx
  - pip install sphinx-autobuild
  - pip install sphinx-autoapi
  - pip install furo
  - sphinx-build -b html -E -a ./docs/ public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

I have used the tags `-E` and `-a` during sphinx-build to force rebuild of all HTML pages, but the updated changes from the docstrings are still not picked up by Sphinx.

I am using sphinx-autoapi, and I have tried to point the `autoapi_dirs` to the correct directory:

```
autoapi_dirs = ['../mypackage']
autoapi_type = "python"

autoapi_options = [
    "members",
    "special-members",
    "undoc-members",
    "show-inheritance",
    "show-module-summary",
    "imported-members"
]
```

For my local build, the documentation can be updated accordingly, but for the deployment on Gitlab pages, each deployed version still sticks to the old documentation. I am not sure what else I can do to resolve this problem? Did I miss anything during the deployment?

Thank you for any suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After close to one week of hunting the bugs, I have managed to resolve the above-mentioned problem:

Only the arguments and typehints part of the docs cannot be shown correctly even after `pip install -e mypackage` every time and making sure that the `conf.py` is pointing to the correct directory.

I found out later that this is caused by `B902` error (Link: https://pypi.org/project/flake8-bugbear/). I have a mixture of different method types in my class, I have previously only used the `self` argument for methods that need to access the attributes of the class, and I didn't used `self` for other methods that do not need the class attributes.

Nevertheless, what is puzzling to me is that `flake8` and and sphinx compilation don't actually flag these as errors. I also have no problems using these methods in scripts either. The only problem is that `sphinx-autoapi` cannot output the docs correctly for these class methods that don't have `self` as the first argument. And I only discovered these errors later when including additional plugin for `flake8` that pick up these errors.